# Is there any part of speech tagger and tokenizer of Tamil language?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp, tamil

I am a beginner in natural language processing. I have to work on different languages that Tamil is one of them. Could I ask from experts whether there is any Tamil language tokenizer code (java,c,python or etc.) and part of speech tagger codes that I use it for my research?

I really appreciate if I can get some experts' opinion here. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of any corpora for Tamil language. If there aren't any available, you could use [NLPf](https://gitlab.com/schrieveslaach/NLPf) to train custom NLP models (tokenization, sentence segmentation, POS tagging) for the Tamil language. I'm happy to demonstrate the project to you.

Comment: @Schrieveslaach  Thank you very much for your help, You are really helpful. Thanks a lot

Comment: you are welcome. :-) Have you tried NLPf? If you did, would you fill out a questionnaire about the project? It shouldn't take longer than fifteen minutes. Could you reach out to me via e-mail?

Comment: @Schrieveslaach, My apologies I did not pay attention `NLPf` is your project. Thank you very much for your help. Sure, definitely I will complete the questionnaire and contact via email. Thanks a lot once again. Sir, You did very big help.

Comment: I'm happy to provide help with NLPf. Just send me an e-mail and I will sent you the questionnaire. You will find my e-mail in the commits or on my website (link is available on my profile).

Comment: did you find my e-mail address?

Comment: @S.EB Im a beginner at NLP, looking for a library for Tokenizing POS tagging and Morphological Analysis  in Tamil. Were you able to find any good resources that you could recommend me? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Schrieveslaach Is there any chance you could help me out on how to train NLP models for tokenizing and POS tagging in Tamil? But i was able to find some Tamil Corpora's as well

Comment: @NivedithaKarmegam, currently I'm very busy due to my job and an up coming conference. Could you reach out to me in about one and a half week?

Comment: @Schrieveslaach Thank you so much! I will contact you in another one and a half weeks time. Thanks again, this would be of great help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found one tool for tokenization [Indic NLP Library](http://anoopkunchukuttan.github.io/indic_nlp_library/). It supports Tamil.

---

I found no POS tagger tools available on the internet, but I have found some papers:

2008 [Morpheme based Language Model
for Tamil Part-of-Speech Tagging](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d721/793e92770c37dd676cd74905add5291c9c81.pdf?_ga=2.156283001.399233541.1517161769-1057452481.1494151046)

2009 [CRF Models for Tamil Part of Speech
Tagging and Chunking](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-642-00831-3_2.pdf)

2009 [Improvement of Rule Based Morphological
Analysis and POS Tagging in Tamil Language
via Projection and Induction Techniques](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ffb7/494c35b766d0cac1a87298ea4f9bf00f5ad2.pdf?_ga=2.146764662.399233541.1517161769-1057452481.1494151046)

**Maybe you can contact the authors for help.**

---

Or if you can speak Tamil, search on the internet(especially university websites) in Tamil, you may find some resources and tools.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It was a big help. You are the best

Answer (score 0):

[Stanza](https://pypi.org/project/stanza/) have.

```py
import logging
import stanza

logging.getLogger('stanza').setLevel(logging.ERROR)

Download and initialize the Tamil model
stanza.download('ta')

nlp = stanza.Pipeline(lang='ta')

# Sample text in Tamil
text = "தமிழ் எங்கள் உயிருக்கு நேர்."
# Process the text
doc = nlp(text)

# Iterate over the sentences and tokens to print POS tags
print(f'{"POS":<7} | {"WORD":<10}')
for sentence in doc.sentences:
    for word in sentence.words:
        print(f"{word.pos:7} | {word.text}")
```

**Output**:

```
POS     | WORD      
PROPN   | தமிழ்
PRON    | எங்கள்
NOUN    | உயிருக்கு
VERB    | நேர்
PUNCT   | .
```